# Ruby on Rails: Modules vs. Classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a function that will be accessible throughout all parts of my program.  I want something like:

```
def GlobalFunctions.my_function(x,y)
    puts x + y
end
```

to be accessible for all models.  Specifically I am trying to use a function like this in my seeds.rb file but I am most likely going to be reusing the code and don't want any redundancy.  Now I know I can make a simple class, but I could also make a module.  What are some reasons to go in either direction? And once I've decided on which type to use, how do I make it accessible throughout the whole program?

I have tried a module, but I keep getting " Expected app/[module file] to define [ModuleName]"

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You'd define a class for something you'll want to make instances of. In this case, a module would probably be better, as modules basically just group code together:

```
module GlobalFunctions
  def self.my_function(x,y)
    puts x+y
  end
end

GlobalFunctions.my_function(4,5) # => 9
```

Alternatively, you could define it on Kernel, and then just call it anywhere. Kernel is where methods like puts are defined.

```
def Kernel.my_function(x,y)
  puts x + y
end

my_function(4,5) # => 9
```

Comment: Is there a specific location for these modules to be saved?

Comment: I usually put modules in the `lib` folder.

Comment: still not clear the difference between class and module.

Answer (score 18):

Adding methods to Kernel (answer from PreciousBodilyFluids) is usually considered a bad smell and can lead to some really hard to find bugs in large projects.

It's much more accepted to relevantly namespace the code and put in to /lib/.

```
class Formatting
  def self.bold(str)
    return "<strong>#{str}</strong>"
  end
end
```

You can then:

```
require 'formatting'
puts Formatting.bold("text")
```

or

```
require 'formatting'
include Formatting

puts bold("text")
```

It'll be clear to anyone who comes to the code later what you're using too. If you're using Rails you won't need the require.

Answer (score 2):

PreciousBodilyFluids is correct, and if this `GlobalFunctions` is part of a RoR project, you may want to name the file `global_functions.rb` and place it in the `lib/` directory to help you avoid the error message you posted at the end of your question.